# How do I connect Power Virtual Agent to Bot Framework Composer?

Tags: power-virtual-agents

I'm trying to use an Adaptive Card I created with Power Virtual Agent via Power Automate. According to the following Microsoft article, I should be able to just click a button on the Topics section of the Power Virtual Agents dashboard, and it'll pop open the Bot Framework Composer, but I don't see this button.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/advanced-bot-framework-composer#troubleshooting

I have installed the Composer, Emulator, and upgraded .Net in preparation. I've tried multiple browsers to see if, by some slim chance, that was the issue. No luck. According to the Power Virtual Agents blog, this feature became a publicly available preview 11/16/2020.

Am I missing something in the settings or installation that would allow me to connect the two?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a MS Teams integrated license or a full license or trial? Based on [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/advanced-bot-framework-composer#troubleshooting), a full license is required to access this capability.

> Bot Framework Composer integration is not available to users who only have the Teams Power Virtual Agents license. You must have a trial or full Power Virtual Agents license.

There was an issue in January 2021 where the button is not showing up for certain users even though they had a full license. This was resolves on January 21st.

Comment: I'm still on the trial.

Comment: still nothing. Do you happen to have a link to any official communication?

Comment: @dnlarralde could you try this now? Something changed 3 hours ago.

Comment: Well, dang, it's there! Thank you!

Comment: @dnlarralde sorry about that :)